# starting a batch file from a linux server using perl

Tags: linux, windows, perl, batch-file, ssh

All,

I have a perl script (which is running on a linux server) that mounts and unmounts windows machines to grab log files. These log files are being moved onto another mounted windows machine. I have a batch file on the receiving computer that sorts these log files. I would like to call that file from the perl script. I am trying to use a linux shell command:

`start $network_dir/logs/sort.bat`

this line is giving me compilation errors, is there another way to run the batch file seeing as the drive is already mounted, or do I need to provide an SSH connection? I also can't figure out how to run the batch file from PuTTy (from Windows -> Linux -> mounted drive)

Thank you in advance

Comment: Mounting the drive only means that the server is allowing you to read the disk. You would have to use telnet or ssh. And I've seen people get into a whole lot of tangles trying to ssh into a windows machine. `start` itself is a cmd *internal* command. (Type `where where` into a command prompt and compare it to `where start` and see how ill-prepared windows is.) There are a lot of hoops you'll have to jump through, unless you simply use the facilities you have in linux, or arrange for a file-trigger to set off the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

`cmd`, the shell that understands `start` and the commands in `sort.bat`, has not been ported to Linux. You cannot execute batch files outside of Windows.

Comment: Note: There is Wine, which allows you to run Windows on a Linux machine.